# Numpyのarangeに関する質問

Tags: python

Numpyのarangeを使ってfor文を回しているのですが，期待したarangeのループ回数でfor文が動作してくれません．
期待する動作は，`0.1575`から`0.2625`まで`0.0105`刻みでループしてほしいです．

現在，python 2.7.10を使用しています．

原因を教えていただきたいです．

まずは，コードは以下になります．

```
for lnaTV in np.arange(0.1575, 0.273, 0.0105):
    print(lnaTV)
```

出力は以下，

```
0.1575
0.168
0.1785
0.189
0.1995
0.21
0.2205
0.231
0.2415
0.252
0.2625
0.273
```

Comment: 問題点が不明です。上記で、うまく動作しているように見えますが、最後の0.273が余分という意味でしょうか？

Comment: 期待する動作は「0.2625まで」としているのに、実際のコードは「0.273まで」になっているのは、意図してでしょうか？素人目にはこの部分を書き換えれば良さそうに見えます。

Comment: `numpy.linspace` を使うと、`np.linspace(0.1575, 0.2625, (0.2625-0.1575)/0.0105+1)`  => `array([0.1575, 0.168, 0.1785, 0.189, 0.1995, 0.21, 0.2205, 0.231, 0.2415, 0.252, 0.2625])` となります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

浮動小数点演算の丸め誤差が原因です。

numpyのarangeの[ドキュメント](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)を見てみると

> stop : number
>   End of interval. The interval does not include this value, except in some cases where step is not an integer and floating point round-off affects the length of out.

とあります。ざっと訳してみると「数列の最後。その数列はこの値を含まない。ただし、stepが整数ではなく、浮動小数点の丸めが出力配列の長さに影響を及ぼす場合を除く」です。

コンピュータ内では、通常、数値は2進数で保持されています。十進数では有限の桁の小数も、2進数では、多くの場合、循環小数になってしまいます。永遠に桁を保存することはできないので、循環小数は途中で切られてしまい、誤差を含んでいます。このため、十進数表現では、誤差の出ない計算も、2進数では誤差が出ることがあります。

今回の場合は、即値の0.273と、0.1575に0.0105を足していって出来た0.273を比べると、後者の方が、ほんのわずか小さくなっているのだと思います。

Comment: なるほど，丸め誤差による影響なのですね．詳しい回答誠にありがとうございます．